# How do I get angular-oauth2-oidc v14 to co-exist with angular/core v 14?

Tags: angular, dependencies, package.json, angular14

I'm using Angular 14.  I have the following dependencies in my package.json

```
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
...
"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^14.0.0",
```

When I start my app, using "ng serve", I get these errors ...

```
./node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/fesm2015/angular-oauth2-oidc.mjs:3611:9-33 - Error: export 'makeEnvironmentProviders' (imported as 'makeEnvironmentProviders') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Compiler, CompilerFactory, Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver ...

Error: node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/provider.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/core"' has no exported member 'EnvironmentProviders'.

1 import { EnvironmentProviders } from '@angular/core';
```

I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot this issue, so maybe a good start might be to ask what version of angular-core 14 plays nicely with angular-oauth2-oidc?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [readme of the project](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc#tested-environment), versioning matches angular version, so `angular-oauth2-oidc : ^14` should work with `angular: ^14`.
Here is a demo where it works https://angular-xejuat.stackblitz.io

Your import issue could be caused by invalid installation, or some other corrupted node_modules state. Try deleting the `node_modules` (and optionally `package-lock.json` as well) and installing dependencies again.

Comment: I tried deleting both package-lock.json and node_modules and re-installing with "npm i --legacy-peer-deps".  I get the same error.

Comment: can you start from the provided stackblitz example and add your other dependencies one by one? Verify that your `devDependencies` are in sync with your main deps, double check angular/cli version and that the Angular version is really what it should be in `node_modules/@angular/core/package.json`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on version `"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^14.0.0"`

It has been fixed on version `"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^14.0.1"`